# is @EnableOAuth2Sso annotation OpenID Connect compliant?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

The *OpenID connect* is about authentication (single sign on)
The *oauth2* is about authorization (but you can still use it for authentication), though it vulnerable to some sorts of Confused Deputy attack.

Therefore the question is :

Is spring `@EnableOAuth2Sso` badly named or the annotation is indeed NOT compliant with OpenID connect spec?

If it would, I would expect it to be called `@EnableOpenIdConnectSso`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `@EnableOAuth2Sso` does not support OpenID Connect. That said, I think that this name can make sense even if it did support OIDC since it could potentially support both. In other words, I'd expect `@EnableOpenIdConnectSso` to only support OIDC, whereas `@EnableOAuth2Sso`, being more generically named, could support both OAuth 2.0 custom flows as well as the OIDC standard.

And while you didn't ask this, I'd actually recommend using [Spring Security's built-in support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login) instead of the plugin project, which has now been deprecated. (That annotation only exists in the deprecated project.) The built-in support **does** support OIDC and will use it automatically when the `openid` scope is present.